# What is the minSDKVersion that support Bottom navigation?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

What is the minSDKVersion that support [Bottom avigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was added in v25.0.0 of the design support library as you can see in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html).
[image]

This library is backwards compatible as far as sdk version **9**. See the value for minSdk [here in the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/AndroidManifest.xml).

Comment: I was just about to write it, you are so fast!

Comment: That's not really accurate. It was added in sdk 25 of the design support library but it is compatible with a min sdk of much lower than that. I have used it with a minSDK of 14 with no issues.

Comment: @drawinfinity damn. That's true. My bad

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to explicitly clarify that the BNV is part of the Support Library, not the Android API/SDK.

Comment: @TimCastelijns sweet. Not sure why but I drew a blank on where to find the minSDK. Funny that its not in the docs.

Comment: @stan0 yes. I think I did that in the first line. If you think it is not clear enough, feel free to edit

Comment: @drawinfinity, Tim Castelijns, I tried with minSDK version-16 and worked fine. Is there any official documentation regarding minSDK?

Comment: Official documentation, no. But you can find it by looking at the source code

Comment: @mridul as a general rule of thumb, unless you are making your app compatible with extremely old sdks you are likely safe using design support library components. Also as long as you have an updated version of AndroidStudio it will usually pop off a warning or error if you try to use something with a minSDK higher than the one you set for the project

Answer (score 1):

Actually I could not find documentation but I have used it with a minSDK of 14 and have not had problems with it. AFAIK all design support library modules are designed to degrade gracefully on lower sdks. As a note I believe your compileSDK version has to match your support library version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use something like [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), you can use with the support library. I used it on a device with API 16, so I guess that's a pretty old API. if you want some tutorial you could use [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/). It's a really nice tutorial, hope you'll find it useful.